# $A \in B$ vs. $A \subset B$ for proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove a few different statements.

The first is if $A \subset B$ and $B \subset C$ then prove $A \subset C$. This one is fairly straight forward, but I'm stuck on how the next one differs.

Prove that if $A \in B$ and $B \in C$ then $A \in C$.

I don't really understand how to put this in logical symbols. I've only seen $a \in A$ written out but never "a set $A$ is an element of a set $B$".

Here's what I have for a proof at this point, assuming I understand what "a set $A$ is an element of a set $B$" means: suppose $A \in B$ and $B \in C$. 
Then $A \in C$.

Comment: Are you sure that you have to prove $A\in B\wedge B\in C\implies A\in C$? Maybe it is $A\in B\wedge B\subseteq C\implies A\in C$.

Comment: @drhab Or the exercise that's been set is actually "For each of the following statements, give a proof or a counterexample."

Comment: @DavidRicherby Or maybe the person who gave the question is just a jerk.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The implication $(A\in B) \wedge (B\in C) \implies A\in C$ is false. Just take $B=\{A\}$ and $C=\{B\} = \{\{A\}\}$ to have a counterexample.

Comment: hmm...And what if $A=\{A\}$? This counterexample only works under the extra condition that the sets are regular.

Comment: @drhab But most people do use regularity, surely - it's one of the ZF axioms.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I know, and see this as a useful answer. However a note on it cannot harm.

Comment: @drhab this counterexample works under the condition that there exists at least one set $A$ such that $A\neq \{A\}$. You can take $A=\{\}$, for example... but I think it is more clear with a generic $A$, because a particular choice of $A$ is misleading.

Comment: The implication is not false for all sets.

Comment: @Bernard: It is if you stick a couple of universal quantifiers on the front, which is clearly what OP was asking about.

Comment: That's what I did in the addition to my answer.

Comment: You are right. The word "only" used in my first comment is not correct and should be left out.

Answer (score 17):

Take $A=\varnothing$, $B=\{\varnothing\}$ and $C=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

Then clearly $A\in B\wedge B\in C$, but $A\in C$ implies $\varnothing=\{\varnothing\}$ wich cannot be true.

This because $\{\varnothing\}$ has elements and $\varnothing$ has not.

We conclude that the implication is false.

Answer (score 6):

Set membership is not like putting stuff in a box.

If you put a box of chocolates into a drawer then it's certainly true that the drawer contains chocolates, but the concept of set membership is different from this. The membership only considers the direct containment, so by the mathematical language the drawer only contains a box (and in that box there's chocolates).

And that's where your reasoning is wrong (mathematically).

Comment: Okay. To make sure I understand, here's a different example. If A⊆B ∧ B∈C ⟹ A ∈ C. The statement is false? Because A could be 1 of the 5 chocolates in a box (element of a set), but the set is in C. so B∈C, but that doesn't mean that A ∈ C because we're not considering each individual element of A here? I'd assume that A is a subset of C though, just not an element.

Comment: No, the analogy doesn't work well with subsets. It were more a analogy to show the difference between the views - mathematically we don't look into the direct members of a set. B being a (direct member) of C doesn't make a part of it a (direct member) of C.

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove that if $A \in B$ and $B \in C$ then $A \in C$ because it is not always true.

Let $B = \{A, 1 \}$. Then $A \in B$

Let $C = \{ B,2\} = \{ \{A, 1 \}, 2 \}$

The members of $C$ are $\{A, 1 \}$ and $2$. So $A \notin C$.

Yes $A$, is in $\{A, 1 \}$, but it is not in $C$.

Comment: Preassumed that $A\neq2$

Answer (score 1):

There are sets for which the relation $A\in B$  is transitive: *ordinals sets*, which are defined as sets on which the relation $x\in y$ is a *strict well-ordering*.

Furthermore for such sets, one has $(A\in B)\Rightarrow(A\subset B)$.

Example:  $X=\bigl\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{ \varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\bigr\}$.

*Added:*

To answer directly the question, the main difference, from a logical point of view, is that, while $(A\in B)\wedge(B\in C)\Rightarrow (A\in C)$ involves individual elements-sets,  $(A\subset B)\wedge(B\subset C)\Rightarrow (A\subset C)$ involves universal quantifiers:
$$\forall x(x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B)\wedge \forall x(x\in B\Rightarrow x\in C)\Rightarrow\forall x(x\in A\Rightarrow x\in C).$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: While it is true that the relation $A\in B$ is transitive for ordinals, that's not what the Question asks.  It is pretty badly worded, but the OP says they are stuck on how a proof involving $A\in B$ "differs" from one involving $A\subseteq B$, and expresses concern about "how to put this in logical symbols". (Not your downvoter BTW.)

Comment: @hardmath:  I felt I had to give some details on ordinals because of Emanuele Paolini's assertion that transitivity is objectively false.

Comment: I see that Answer gives an example to show the implication $A\in B \wedge B\in C \implies A \in C$ can fail, which is an important difference between set membership and set inclusion.  Surely your recent comment there that "the implication is not false for all sets" suffices to make your point?

Comment: I added a direct (partial) answer to the question.

Comment: Your placement of $\forall x$ seems unwarranted

Comment: Oops! I forgot to write the implications. Thank you for pointing it!